# Sorting specified data in WHERE clause access sql

Tags: sql, ms-access-2010

My below tables are excel sheet data converted as access table using VBA. I'm sorting  the data where *EID<>7006* or *EID<>3456* i.e sorting all column data but not either EID=7006 or EID=3456. But sometimes EID=7006 won't present in the table based on the excel file i convert.

Table1 has EID=7006 and EID=3456

```
  Description    EID        Basecode        
   -----------    ----       ---------    
  ssdad          3456       S2378797     
  gfd            1002       S1164478     
  gfdsffsdf      1003       R1165778     
  ssdad          3456       M0007867     
  gfd            1005       N7765111     
  gfdsffsdf      7006        W5464111     
  gfd            1005       N7765111
```

some times Table1 does not have EID=7006

```
 Description    EID        Basecode        
   -----------    ----       ---------    
  ssdad          3456       S2378797     
  gfd            1002       S1164478     
  gfdsffsdf      1003       R1165778     
  ssdad          3456       M0007867     
  gfd            1005       N7765111     
  gfdsffsdf       88        W5464111     
  gfd            1005       N7765111
```

If i specify my query ignoring both *7006* or *3456* like in table1, since i don't know whether *EID=7006* present or not, i represent in the query like

```
   SELECT Description,EID,Basecode from table2 where EID<>7006 or EID<>3456
```

Still i see *7006* and  *3456* in the  result query.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like your issue is using OR when you mean AND

```
SELECT Description,EID,Basecode from table2 where EID<>7006 AND EID<>3456
```

Answer (score 3):

A *slightly* cleaner query would be:

```
SELECT Description, EID, Basecode 
FROM table2 
WHERE EID NOT IN (7006, 3456)
```

Answer (score 0):

Using `OR` in a `WHERE` clause is very tricky. in this case, your `OR` operator is acting like a `UNION`. It is behaving as if you had written this:

```
SELECT Description,EID,Basecode 
from table2 
where EID<>7006 

union

SELECT Description,EID,Basecode 
from table2 
where EID<>3456
```

Since each set contains the EID value from the other set, you will continue to see the EID values you are trying to filter out.

What you need to do is write:

`SELECT Description,EID,Basecode from table2 where (EID<>7006 and EID<>3456)`

or you can phrase it like the following, which will produce the same result as using the logical `AND` operator:

`SELECT Description,EID,Basecode from table2 where EID NOT IN ("7006","3456")`